# Excel VBA for opening listed files and saving to new listed location

Tags: vba

I am very new to vba and want to build a code to function the below requirement.

There are multiple file names in listed in an excel sheet from a particular folder, these needs to be opened one by one -> delete column A -> rename with the name defined in the excel list -> save on new path after creating new  directory if does'nt exist which is also defined in the file.

This is my sample data[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A51Gd.jpg)
please assist

Comment: This is not a code writing service.

Comment: sorry for this, I have tried to search through multiple codes however cant amended to the one required . Could anyone please assist ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open and close files: http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/close-open.html
2. Delete a column: https://analysistabs.com/vba/delete-entire-column-excel-macro-example-code/
3. Create folder: https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/mkdir.php
4. Rename files: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/586216-excel-visual-basic-applications-rename-existing-file.html
5. Move files: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/637606-move-files-another-folder-visual-basic-applications.html

This should give you a good start, post your code if you get stuck.